# How to force CSS prefer-color-scheme to dark globally in all chrome pages

Tags: css, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, themes, color-scheme

There is a [known bug in Chromium](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=998903) where it can't detect the preferred theme of the system OS, so it always sets it as default (light theme).

An often given "solution" is enable the Chrome flag #enable-force-dark, but it doesn't really solve the problem, the CSS "prefer-color-scheme" media query is always set to `light`, no matter what you do.

One temporary solution that I think is to force the "prefer-color-scheme"  query globally on Chrome. I know that you can force it in the Dev tools at F12 `Three dots > More tools > Rendering > Emulate CSS media feature prefers-color-scheme`, but it will only be active in the current page context for Developing purposes, so, **How can I set the `prefer-color-scheme` to dark globally?**, maybe with a Chrome extension?

Comment: I really want to do this as well. The light mode is killing my eyes at night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround:

Launch Chrome/Chromium with the [`--force-dark-mode`](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/#force-dark-mode) flag (aka command line switch).

```
google-chrome --force-dark-mode
```

Put this flag in `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` file, specifically in the `Exec` key. Preferably add it to `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` since user entries take precedence over system entries, and this key wont be overwritten by Chrome updates.